# How to get reputation from posting an edit as an anonymous user

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, anonymous

I  made an edit as an anonymous user. How can I get the reputation if my edit is accepted?

Comment: [Anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(group)) gets reputation if the edit is approved.

Comment: If *you* get the reputation, the editor is no longer anonymous. Sorry, I don't get your question.

Comment: Theoretically the team can merge different accounts. But it requires CM or higher intervention, even over the level of the moderators. For a single +2 rep edit, don't waste their time. Rather write 10 good answers, but this time from your account :-)

Comment: oh wow this has a lot of downvotes. I guess i am not good at asking questions. :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't have your cheese and eat it.

You won't. You get reputation *as* the user who did the edit, and if you figured you wanted to edit anonymously for any reason, you're not getting the reputation for the edit.

So if you want to get reputation for an edit, you're going to have to own up, and take responsibility for it too.